# FatalErrorException: Parse: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC in

Tags: php, symfony, syntax-error

I am new in using symfony2 and I am currently studying the book documentation found in their website but I have come across with this one, I am getting this error with my controller with no unexpected or missing formats with my code:

```
    <?php

    namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Controller;

    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

    public function showproductAction()
    {
        $product = new Product();
        $product->setName('A Foo Bar');
        $product->setPrice('19.99');
        $product->setDescription('Lorem ipsum dolor');

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($product);
        $em->flush();

        return new Response('Created product id '.$product->getId());
    }
```

Basically I've already created the needed entities(class) but I really don't know what this error really means (I've encounter this one with just missing semicolons or bracket but now it just basically says that there's a parse error but not pointing it.) Can someone help me to understand what it really says?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the action method inside a controller class.

I suggest you start with basic Object-Oriented PHP before diving into Symfony2.

Comment: That works!, sorry I forgot to put it because I've basically copied from the symfony page not thinking about the previous topics I am trying. Thanks! but now I got this problem `Class "Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.` I've already created the Product entity inside the entity directory through the command line but I don't know where I go wrong.